# error label for the inputbox doesn't point to the left but upwards in semantic ui

Tags: semantic-ui, formvalidation.io, error-messages-for

```
i have linked copy code here please find the result
```

https://codepen.io/manikandanpa/pen/RyeEpX?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `.ui.labeled.input` into a `div` with `.fluid.field`

```
<form class="ui form">
  <div class="fluid field">
    <div class="ui labeled input">
      <div class="ui label">
        Example
      </div>
      <input class="ui input " type="text" name="example" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4x8d56sw/

Comment: its working fine. but why it again pointing upward,not left , help me.